# how can I position an element on top of a div witouth using negative margins?

Tags: css, position, margin

how can I position an element on top of a div without using negative margins or padding?
check the image to see what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

grey area is the div #content and blue is h1. I need the h1 to be inside of the #content. I assume I could achieve this if I place h1 before #content div and use z-index but thats not the only way, is it?

```
<div id="content">
<h1>text here</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Just use negative-margin, it is perfectly valid and works with all browsers. And there is no such thing as negative padding. Using negative margin is the cleanest, shortest way to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `position`ing.

```css
#content h1 {position: relative; top: -15px;}
```

Or to put it in a better way, give `position`ing for both.

```css
#content {position: relative;}
#content h1 {position: absolute; top: -15px;}
```

For the query about negative `top` values:

> Negative values are allowed and would result in the element being moved in the opposite direction to those already stated above.

References:

- [Sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/top)

Comment: @devotchkah Yes, obviously negative `top` values are allowed. Also, negative margins are valid too! :)

Comment: @devotchkah Added references too! Please check.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks! I'm trying my best here to follow best practices

Comment: @PraveenKumar damn .. i should not have gave answer like that +1

Comment: i thought user wants that blue box in gray box just misread question